# Two divs on page like columns, first div fills all space after second div

Tags: css, html

Here is the html code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="ads">...</div>
<div id="content">...</div>
</div>
```

I know how to place divs like columns on page, but i cant figure out is it possible to achieve that content div fills all space after ads div? 
One obvious solution is to put ads-div into content-div like in below answer. But there is one problem. Content div may include any other html code, not only plain text. So, for example, if i place inner div with style "width:100%", 100% means all width of content div, its not pay attention to ads-div. 
I guess its not possible to achieve this by keeping two divs separated.
Please see the screenshot for demo:
[image]

Comment: IMO that is not possible without overlapping your content partially. The content area cannot have two different widths.

Answer (score 2):

You could re-arrange your elements so ads are inside content `<div>`. See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bPZXu/) for example:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="ads">...</div>
        Lorem ipsum ...
    </div>
</div>
```

With CSS:

```
#ads {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    float: right;
}
#content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: I guess he wants to pull the adjacent container, like if a is greater in height, pull the b element, if b is high, pull the a element, *but i cant figure out is it possible to achieve that content div fills all space after ads div*

Comment: @Mr.Alien - Looking at OP's second image, I guess he want's to have content "surround" the ads (which are shorter than content). He also stated: "(...) content div fills all space after ads div"

Comment: Lets see, if that's the thing than solution is pretty simple, but after reading this line *but i cant figure out is it possible to achieve that content div fills all space after ads div* I think he wants to pull the adjacent element :)

Comment: Now i have html markup like in your answer. But there is one problem. Content div may include any other html code, not only plain text. So, for example, if i place inner div with style "width:100%", 100% means all width of content div, its not pay attention to ads-div. Sorry for my bad eng.

Comment: @ifeelgood - see [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bPZXu/1/) on how you might approach that (use `margin-right` equal to the width of ads div).

Comment: @kamituel - ok, but its not the solution, because content is always dynamic and i never know what time content-div is higher. So its not possible to use style margin-right: 100px; for all content code.

Answer (score 1):

Now floating the elements on the page won't help you achieve that, if you want, you can use `display: flex;`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fKmMH/)

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrap {
    display: flex;    
}

.first {
    width: 80%;
    background: #f00;
}

.second {
    width: 20%;
    background: #00f;
}
```

---

Or, if you are looking to support legacy browser, consider using `display: table;` and `display: table-cell` respectively...

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fKmMH/1/)

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrap {
    display: table;    
    width: 100%;
}

.first {
    width: 80%;
    display: table-cell;
    background: #f00;
}

.second {
    width: 20%;
    display: table-cell;
    background: #00f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have tried this but not by div but i have used paragraph and div in my case.

you can try this also

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
  <div id="ads">...</div>
  <p>
  //your content
  </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

if you don't want to use inline css then add

```
#ads{
float:right
width:200px;
}
```

check (http://jsfiddle.net/q8NJk/)

and you can get padding or margin as you want

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the `<div id="ads">`into your `<div id="content">`.

Heres the whole code:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="content"><div id="ads">...</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    #content {
           width:600px;
           height:500px;
           background-color:red;
    }

    #ads {
            height: 300px;
            width:100px;
            background-color:blue;
            float:right;
    }
```

Or just have a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7XfPT/) fiddle.