# Make 2 divs have same height as parent

Tags: css, layout

I created a layout with 2 columns by divs, however the columns's height are difference. I want a div will be expanded as height as another one.

The link is my demo http://jsbin.com/UjiyufO/2

Kindly please give me any suggestion.

Comment: Refer my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/19630045/1542290

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Alien, however 2 my divs have to `display:block` Cannot apply table and `table-cell` in my personal reason.

Comment: In your demo, how can I make 'hello' in first column at the top of div and 'hello' in the second column is margin-top 10px

Comment: If you cannot use `display: table` than go for flex, else you need to use JS, and about the comment, here's the solution http://jsfiddle.net/fKmMH/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add this Javascript it will work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myheight= $('#header').height(); 
    var thatheight= $('#content').height(); 
    if(myheight>thatheight)
    {
        $('#content').css('height',myheight)
    }
    else
    {
        $('#header').css('height',thatheight)
    }
});
```

Check this [JSbin](http://jsbin.com/iBInOrU/2/edit)

Comment: Thanks @Deekey for the solution, however the div will be not smoothly rendered. Do you have any suggestions for that?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the parent element #main has an exactly height, or the 2 divs' 100% height couldn't work.

You can also use this:

```
#main{ overflow:hidden; }
#header,#content{           
  width: 40%;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom:-1000px;
  padding-bottom:1000px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Set your 2 divs with the same height. Example :

```
#main div{
    height: 500px;
}
```

In your demo, there is a tag `<div>` with the id=main which have 2 divs. And there just set the 2 divs with the same height.

Comment: Thanks @david, the content in my page just for demo, content may be longer than and the height has to expandable same as child, and another div also expands as same as another one (and parent div as well)